# C++ - program crashes when defining custom destructor

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a class like this:

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo* next = nullptr;

    Foo() = default;

    Foo(Foo *next){
        Foo::next = new Foo(*next);
    }

    Foo(const Foo &copy){
        next = new Foo(*copy.next);
    }


    ~Foo(){
        delete next;
    }
}
```

It compiles, but when I instantiate the class anywhere, the program crashes. When using a debugger a "breakpoint trap" is triggerd at `delete next`.

Why is that?

Edit:

The problem was, that there were instances where `next` could be set to pointers created outside of the class. I assumed you could delete pointers created anywhere.

Comment: "Why is that?" because you break rule of 3/5/0

Comment: What is the other stuff?

Comment: Your program should not attempt to delete something that has not been previously initialized with new.

Comment: Show us more context please..

Comment: Sorry I snipped out the other stuff. There is also a copy-constructor and an assignment operator.

Comment: it compiles....

Comment: please create a [MCVE]

Comment: Your copy constructor runs an endless recursive loop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your pointer `next` is uninitialized, pointing to *something* unknown. `delete` will (most likely, if you are lucky) throw trying to delete it. Make sure the pointer points to memory allocated with `new` or is a `nullptr`.

Comment: you should know better than answering a question that forces you to make so much assumptions because it lacks any resemblance of a MCVE.

Comment: @bolov The code he did post contained an obvious error... I'm kinda surprised that you think I should be psychic and see that this error would turn out to be "not the error". There was no assumption on my part... that code had a bug right as written here and I pointed it out.

Comment: Thanks I had a couple instances where I was accepting a pointer created outside of the class. I have fixed this now. Thank you :)

Comment: @nvoigt when I saw that initial scheleton code with `[other stuff]` it was clear (to me at least) that he just showed the declaration and the destructor and left out vital parts of code. The `[other stuff]` told me he didn't intend that as a MCVE and that his real code has some sort of initialization/assignment for `next`